# Windows 10 booting old installation after SSD clone

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub, xubuntu

I recently cloned my system drive from a 128GB SSD to a 500GB SSD and now I am facing some weird problems.

First up, let me describe my old setup:

- Drive 0 (128GB SSD)

  - GRUB 2
  - Windows 10 system-reserved
  - Windows 10
  - Windows 10 recovery
  - Xubuntu 16.04
- Drive 1 (1TB HD)

  - Shared data
- Drive 2 (250GB HDD)

  - More data
- Drive 3 (128GB SSD)

  - Even more data

Now drives 1, 2 and 3 are not of interest here. I took out drive 3 and put in the new 500GB SSD in its place. Then I ran `dd` from the Xubuntu installation on drive 0 and cloned the entire drive 0 to drive 3 (the new 500GB SSD). So at this point, my setup looked like this (drives 1 and 2 omitted for clarity):

- Drive 0 (128GB SSD)

  - GRUB 2
  - Windows 10 system-reserved
  - Windows 10
  - Windows 10 recovery
  - Xubuntu 16.04
- Drive 3 (500GB SSD)

  - GRUB 2
  - Windows 10 system-reserved
  - Windows 10
  - Windows 10 recovery
  - Xubuntu 16.04
  - Unallocated space

I then rebooted and deleted the duplicate Xubuntu partition on drive 3 as well as the unnecessary Windows 10 recovery partition, so drive 3 then looked like this:

- Drive 3 (500GB SSD)

  - GRUB 2
  - Windows 10 system-reserved
  - Windows 10
  - Unallocated space

I then somehow booted into the Windows 10 installation on drive 3 using the GRUB on drive 0 (I specifically selected drive 0 from the BIOS so I could be sure I know what's going on) and used the disk management tool in Windows 10 to enlarge the Windows 10 system partition on the currently running installation on drive 3. At that point, drive 3 looked like this:

- Drive 3 (500GB SSD)

  - GRUB 2
  - Windows 10 system-reserved
  - Windows 10

Now I don't exactly remember what else I did but right now the situation is as follows:

- I have set up drive 0 as the default boot drive
- In the GRUB in drive 0, I have set up boot entries for the Xubuntu installation on drive 0 and the Windows 10 installations on drives 0 and 3
- I confirmed that the Windows 10 entries point to their respective drives (hd0 and hd3)
- No matter which one of the Windows 10 entries I select upon boot, it always boots the old Windows 10 installation on drive 0 instead of the new one on drive 3

I thought that maybe something in the Windows 10 part of the bootloader still pointed to drive 0, so I checked the BCD file on drive 3 with BootIce and indeed it pointed to drive 0 (at least that's what BootIce showed), so I changed it to point to drive 3 and verified that it had actually been changed.

Still, this did not fix my problem and now I am at a loss. What else can I do to get the Windows 10 installation to boot from drive 3?

Comment: Try changing some settings in your BIOS. Probably increase the boot priority of Drive 3?

Comment: The thing is, I explicitly selected drive 3 in the boot menu and explicitly booted the GRUB entry for hd3,msdos1. Yet it booted hd0,msdos1.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) may help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I already used Grub Customizer and made sure the entries were pointing to the right partitions, so that does unfortunately not help me either.

Comment: There is a high chance that this solution will not work, but have you tried switching the slots of the two drives?

Comment: Yes, I tried that at some point during the process, and it did boot Win10 on drive 3 once, but when I went back to restart, it just reverted back to drive 0. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the BCD to point to your new installation of Windows.

Of course, since you have now two Windows system-reserved partitions, you also have two distinct BCD, so you need to update both of them.

For the BCD on the new disk 3, the easiest way is to unplug temporarily disk 0, boot the machine from disk 3 through the Windows repairing tool, and let it perform reparation which will add the new installation of Windows. If it does not erase the previous configuration (not sure), you will have a working multi-boot configuration when using that BCD when plugging back disk 0, provided that you are using **that** BCD, i.e. starting Windows Boot Manager on disk 3.

For the BCD on the old disk 0, you need to start the Windows Boot Manager from disk 0, start reparation using command line, and use `BootRec` with /ScanOS to make it discovering your new version of Windows.